# Django OAuth toolkit: Automatically generate a client_id and client_secret for new user?

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-oauth, django-oauth-toolkit

I am using OAuth client credentials to offer my customers access to our API so they can integrate with their systems.

To register an application and generate a client_id and client_secret the Django-oauth-toolkit documentation says the form `o/applications/register/` must be completed ([documentation here](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#client-credential)). Is it possible to automatically issue a client_id and client_secret to my user when they sign up instead of directing them to this form ?

Comment: The client should complete the form in `o/applications/register/` to allow the client to specify the `redirect URIs` which is necessary for security reasons.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example to get the data that you need. All you need to do is to integrate this into your custom user model.

```
from oauth2_provider.models import get_application_model
Application = get_application_model()
app = Application()
app.name = 'test'
app.client_type = 'confidential'
app.authorization_grant_type = 'password'
app.user_id = 1
app.save()

#client_id:
app.client_id

#client_secret:
app.client_secret
```